# Cannot convert value of type '[String:Any]?' to expected argument type '_?'

Tags: ios, swift

The P and R is genericity types

```
open func route<P,R>(url:URL , param : P? ) -> R?{
    guard let s = url.scheme ,let h = url.host  else{
        #if DEBUG
            print("url error")
        #endif
        return nil
    }

    let urlString = "\(s)://\(h)\(url.path)"


    guard let t = self.urlTaskMap[urlString] as? RoyTaskClosure<P,R> else {

        print("closure unmatched,url -> \(urlString)")

        return nil
    }

    let returnValue = t(param)

    return returnValue
}
```

And when I invoke the function like

```
public func viewController(url:URL,param:[String:Any]?) -> RoyProtocol?{
    if let vc = self.route(url: url, param: param){
        return vc
    }
    return nil
}
```

The Xcode show me a error message

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String:Any]?' to expected argument type '_?'
```

God! Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please include the code in your question with proper code formatting and do not include a screenshot of it.

Comment: Please paste the code as text instead of using a picture. Why do people do this anyway? *How* is it easier to make a screenshot, crop it, and upload it instead of just Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V the text?

Comment: What is the class type P in the screenshot?

Comment: is a generic func

Comment: @DávidPásztor  Is it ok?

Comment: @mag_zbc I've fixed it

Comment: @SahebRoy The P and R is genericity types

Comment: Invocation of the deity is inappropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: P is supposed to be a dictionary with String as key and anyvalue as its value, but its not, can you share the implementation of P class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Replace your method with this

```
public func viewController(url:URL,param:[String:Any]?) -> RoyProtocol?{
    let vc: RoyProtocol? = self.route(url: url, param: param)
    return vc
}
```

Comment: It's good,but I recognize that when I invoke the function like  `let vc: RoyProtocol? = self.route(url: url, param: nil) `  it shows the same error

Comment: I know it's weird but you can try   
  let _: RoyProtocol? = route(url: url, param: Optional<Any>.none)
if you want to pass nill